# incremental css3 fadein

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, timeout

How might I do this? I'm trying to use css3 only for performance reasons (fade in can get kind of choppy).

Right now they all happen at the same time.

```
function fadeInPlaylist(elem) {
    elem.css('opacity',1);
}

$(window).load(function() {
   $('.playlist').each(function(i) {
      setTimeout(fadeInPlaylist($(this)),2500*i);
   });
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are calling `setTimeout` incorrectly.

`setTimeout(fadeInPlaylist($(this)),2500*i);`

should be:

`setTimeout(function(){fadeInPlaylist($(this));},2500*i);`

Also, here's a working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/q7Wa8/

Answer (score 1):

If you really need to do it with CSS3 only, use this code:

```
@keyframes reset {
    0% { opacity: 0; }
    100% { opacity: 0; }
}
@keyframes fade-in {
    0% { opacity: 0; }
    60% { opacity: 0; }
    100% { opacity: 1; }
}
.playlist {
    animation-name: reset, fade-in;
    animation-duration: 2.5s;
    animation-timing-function: ease-in;
    animation-iteration-count: 1;
    animation-delay: 0, 0;
}
```

But you'll have compatibility issues.
Here's the cross-browser code, doesn't work in IE:

```
@keyframes reset { 0% { opacity: 0; } 100% { opacity: 0; } }
@keyframes fade-in { 0% { opacity: 0; } 60% { opacity: 0; } 100% { opacity: 1; } }
@-webkit-keyframes reset { 0% { opacity: 0; } 100% { opacity: 0; } }
@-webkit-keyframes fade-in { 0% { opacity: 0; } 60% { opacity: 0; } 100% { opacity: 1; } }
@-moz-keyframes reset { 0% { opacity: 0; } 100% { opacity: 0; } }
@-moz-keyframes fade-in { 0% { opacity: 0; } 60% { opacity: 0; } 100% { opacity: 1; } }
@-o-keyframes reset { 0% { opacity: 0; } 100% { opacity: 0; } }
@-o-keyframes fade-in { 0% { opacity: 0; } 60% { opacity: 0; } 100% { opacity: 1; } }
.playlist {
    animation-name: reset, fade-in;
    animation-duration: 2.5s;
    animation-timing-function: ease-in;
    animation-iteration-count: 1;
    animation-delay: 0, 0;
    -webkit-animation-name: reset, fade-in;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 2.5s;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 0, 0;
    -moz-animation-name: reset, fade-in;
    -moz-animation-duration: 2.5s;
    -moz-animation-timing-function: ease-in;
    -moz-animation-iteration-count: 1;
    -moz-animation-delay: 0, 0;
    -o-animation-name: reset, fade-in;
    -o-animation-duration: 2.5s;
    -o-animation-timing-function: ease-in;
    -o-animation-iteration-count: 1;
    -o-animation-delay: 0, 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `fadeTo` with `delay` but if you want to do it your way try this:

```
function fadeInPlaylist() {
    $(this).css('opacity',1);
}

$(window).load(function() {
   $('.playlist').each(function(i, e) {
     setTimeout(function(){ fadeInPlaylist.call(e); }, 1000 * i);
   });
});
```

**Demo:** http://jsbin.com/oyazof/1/edit

**Edit:**

If you want to do it with CSS3 transitions you can just add a class instead of changing the css from jQuery.

**jQuery:**

```
function fadeInPlaylist() {
  $(this).addClass('opacity');
}
```

**CSS:**

```
.opacity {
  -webkit-transition: opacity .5s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: opacity .5s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: opacity .5s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: opacity .5s ease-in-out;
  transition: opacity .5s ease-in-out;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

**Demo with CSS3 transitions:** http://jsbin.com/oyazof/3/edit

Answer (score -1):

Just change:

```
elem.css('opacity',1);
```

To:

```
elem.fadeTo('fast', 1);
```

Comment: He's using CSS3 animations. Also, this won't make a difference.